# How do I setup a subdomain in apache2 on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apache2, ruby, rails

I have an apache server running on port 80 and I want to have a subdomain that points to port 3000 on the same server. My server on port 3000 is a ruby on rails server, but ideally I can host my main website on apache2 on port 80, and then a subdomain like api.mycompany.com which handles API requests specifically on port 3000. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

create two A records on point to same server

**example.com** --> 87.45.34.31 ( replace with yours server's IP address )
**api.example.com** --> 87.45.34.31 (replace with yours IP)

Create a **VirtualHost** for domain example.com on Apache for your frontend static files pointing to /var/www/html.
create a another **Virualhost** for api.example.com with reverse proxy on port localhost:3000

some reference:-
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use Apache as what's called a "reverse proxy". That's basically telling the Apache server "whatever comes in at this virtual host, send it over to 1.2.3.4:3000, and deliver the response that came from there".

For Apache, this can be done with the module `mod_proxy`, which supplies directives like `ProxyPass` and ProxyPassReverse`. The module should have been installed with your standard Apache setup. You can check whether the output of` apache2ctl -M`contains something along the lines of`proxy_module (shared)'.

Then you setup an additional virtual host that handles the hostname `api.mycompany.com`. Within this virtual host, you set up the reverse proxy

```
ProxyPass "/"  "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
```

assuming your Rails app is running on `http://127.0.0.1:3000` from the server's perspective.

There maybe additional considerations depending on what your Rails app exactly needs (like [ProxyPreserveHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost), to name one example). But this is the basic principle.

Some additional thoughts:

- Don't forget to check whether there's a DNS record for `api.mycompany.com`, and whether that record points to your server.
- Make sure the server running your Rails app is only reachable from `localhost` (something between `127.0.0.1` and `127.255.255.254`). There's no need to have the app reachable from a public ip any more, that's Apache's job now.